# Max no. of items in a checklist on Trello

Tags: trello

In Trello, is there a limit on the number of items a checklist of a card can have? Or you can just add an infinite amount of items to a checklist?

Answer (score 4):

You can add an unlimited number of checklist items. You can also have an unlimited number of checklists.

Comment: As of 2021 this is no longer true. See other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like these days the max number of checklist items is 200. Once you hit that, you get a message at the bottom of the list saying "Too many items in this checklist. Remove some to add more."

Comment: +1 I just ran into this. This answer should be the accepted answer now.